how to make a spring object that pushes the player horizontally?
public class spring : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] public float jumpHeight = 10f;

    private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
    {
        if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("Player"))
        {
            collision.gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(Vector2.up * jumpHeight, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
        }
    }
}

I've made an upwards spring and it was pretty easy to make, I thought it'd be as easy to make a sideways spring but I'm having no luck right now. The script above is said upward spring script. I also know that I have to do something with direction since the player would be going toward the spring to hit it, then get shot back.
I've tried to adapt my upward spring script so that you go in the direction specified in the script (for example, Vector2.right to go right) but I'm guessing it simply doesn't and can't work that way. All the posts I've seen online when trying to solve my issue seem to either be about something else in unity coincidentally called a spring, or how to push an object as the player
edit:
the actual results for Vector2.right doesn't change the direction, it just bounces the player anyway. Also, I renamed the jumpHeight variable to rightForce, but I'm sure that has nothing to do with it not working. Unity showed no errors.
    bool IsGrounded()
    {
        return GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity.y == 0;
    }
    [SerializeField] private float speed = 0;
    [SerializeField] private float jumpHeight = 0;
    [SerializeField] private float FastFallSpeed = 0;
    [SerializeField] private Rigidbody2D rb;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        rb.velocity = new Vector2(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * speed, rb.velocity.y);

        if (IsGrounded())
        {
            if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W))
            {
                rb.velocity = new Vector2(rb.velocity.x, jumpHeight);
            }

        }
    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if (!IsGrounded())
        {
            if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S))
            {
                rb.velocity = new Vector2(rb.velocity.x, FastFallSpeed);
            }
        }
    }


Also, here is the character movement code

My guess would be that it works for the UP direction because here you use the gravity so jumping is not further affected by user input. But for the horizontal direction you have to "fight" against the user input which otherwise simply overrules the effect of the spring. So you would probably need to either redirect the entire movement direction or add enough force to overrule the input, or add mechanics to block the input for a moment

I think more force should do it. Docs say that Impulse is force/mass, so take a look at your jumpheight value and your rigidbody.mass to make sense of it and play around with your values to find the right one.

Let's improve it !
We will use tranform.up as the direction (This is the green arrow you can see when you select the gameobject)
Make sure that your spring sprite point toward this green arrow.
Then simply change your script to use tranform.up
public class spring : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] public float jumpForce = 10f;

    private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
    {
        if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("Player"))
        {
            collision.gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(transform.up * jumpForce , ForceMode2D.Impulse);
        }
    }
}

Note : This "spring" script should be at the root of your spring, not in a child.
Now if you rotate your spring it should correctly send your player in the same direction as the green arrow :)
Don't forget that there is physical friction between your character and the ground so you might need to increase the force of the horizontal spring to counter that.
Edit : I just saw derHugo comment's. He's right, be careful not to overwrite the spring force with your inputs.
You cant write let's say :
rigibody.velocity = someComputedVelocity
This "=" will overwrite the forces

hi, thank you for the help, the code doesn't work for horizontal movement, but when I position the spring in a general up/down position (for example, 45 degrees up or down), the spring wouldn't shoot me 45 degrees, but it'd shoot me straight down or straight up. I set the force to 100 to test but if overwriting is still the problem then I don't understand why.

@sigma I'm pretty sure you are overwriting the rigidbody.velocity.x somewhere in your code.
Try commenting the code of your character movement. Make him spawn above a spring, if the spring works then the error is in your character's movement code

hi! sorry for the late response.. I actually don't know if I can attach code to comments, but I've attached it to the original post by editing it :)

@sigma Then yeah you are definetly overwriting the velocity.
Keep in mind that to have a good physic you should only add/remove velocity but never set it.
By using an equal, you are overwriting the forces of other sources.
Try replacing the first line of your update function with this :
float computedInputVel = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * speed;
if (Mathf.Abs(rb.velocity.x) < Mathf.Abs(computedInputVel))
{
rb.velocity = new Vector2(computedInputVel, rb.velocity.y);
}
// That's not a pretty fix though

The fix I sent you should only allow you to overwrite the X force if the actual velocity is lower than what your inputs can do.
This is certainly not a good fix, since we still use the equal. It wont allow you to counter the velocity of the spring and will feel rigid. But it's enough to show you that you were overwriting
